# Density Dependent Growth

Tags: r, data-modeling

I'm trying to create a graph in R to show the carrying capacity of a population using an example given to me which is:

```
install.packages("deSolve", dependencies = TRUE)

clogistic <- function(times, y, parms){
n <- y[1]
r <- parms[1]
alpha <- parms [2]
dN.dt <- r * n * (1 - alpha * n)
return(list(c(dN.dt)))
}

prms <- c(r = 1, alpha = 0.01)
init.N <- c(1)
t.s <- seq(0.1, 10, by = 0.1)
library(deSolve)
out <- ode(y = init.N, times = t.s, clogistic, parms = prms)

plot(out[,1], out[,2], type="l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "N", col = "blue", lwd = 2)
```

Now I'm using this to try and show a starting population of 178 with an increase of 21 for 15 time steps. But when I try to change the formula it decreases and bottoms out after one time step and stays bottom for the remainder of the time.
I've tried changing init.N <- c(1) to c(178) which it does but then bottoms out. I've tried changing prms <- c(r = 1, alpha = 0.01) to (r = 21, along with the change in initial population change and without but it just doesn't increase. What is it that I am missing? Knowing R it's going to be something small but I just keep missing it.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: to follow up on @BondedDust's answer: the more usual form of the logistic equation in ecology is `r * n * (1 - n/K)`, where `K` is the carrying capacity (= stable equilbrium value as long as `r>0`, `K>0`, `n(0)>0`). That might make things easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the differential equation that is being integrated:

```
 dN.dt <- r * n * (1 - alpha * n)
```

If you want an asymptote of n= 200 then set alpha to 1/200 so that the rate of change will go to zero when n gets to 200:

```
prms <- c(r = 1, alpha = .005)
init.N <- 178
t.s <- seq(0.1, 10, by = 0.1)
library(deSolve)
out <- ode(y = init.N, times = t.s, clogistic, parms = prms)

plot(out[,1], out[,2], type="l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "N", col = "blue", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

With a  starting value of 178, the rate of change will be negative when alpha is greater than 1/178, will be flatline with alpha == 1/178, and will be logistic when alpha is less than 1/178.

To go from 300 to 200 you would keep alpha = 1/200 and start at 300:

```
prms <- c(r = 1, alpha = 1/200)
init.N <- c(300)
t.s <- seq(0.1, 10, by = 0.1)
out <- ode(y = init.N, times = t.s, clogistic, parms = prms)
plot(out[,1], out[,2], type="l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "N", col = "blue", lwd = 2)
```

[image]